# Trying to understand ::before - strange (to me) behavior?

Tags: css

I've been trying to understand how ::before and ::after work.

According to MDN, `In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the selected element.`

So I've set up an HTML file like this:

```css
.test::before {
  content: "..";
  font-size: 200px;
}

.test li:first-child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="test">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

In my opinion, there should be no element of green color.

.test li:first-child should not select anything, because the first-child of the ul should be this ::before pseudo-element.

But 1 is selected though.

Why? Can you help me understand?

Thanks.

Comment: The MDN isn't accurate in this case because ::before will not become the ::first-child from a selector perspective but only from content perspective

Comment: `::before` etc, all this content is not actually present in the DOM but can be manipulated.

Comment: You might find this [CSS-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/a-little-reminder-that-pseudo-elements-are-children-kinda/) interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

::before pseudo-element in not actually a DOM element, appears on the page after DOM load. In this case everything is right - first li element is :first-child.